# Scala WithColumn only if both columns exists

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have seen some variations of this question asked but havent found exactly what Im looking for.  Here is the question:

I have some report names that I have collected in a dataframe and pivoted.  The trouble I am having is regarding the resilience of the report_name.  I cant be assured that every 90 days data will be present and that Rpt1, Rpt2, and Rpt3 will be there.  So how do I go about creating a calculation ONLY if the column is present. I have outlined how my code looks right now.  It works if all columns are there, but Id like to future proof it to ensure that if the report is not present in the 90 day window the pipline will not error out, but instead just skip the .withColumn addition

```
df1=(reports.alias("r")
.groupBy(uniqueid)
.filter("current_date<=90")
.pivot(report_name)

**
Result would be the following columns uniqueid Rpt1, Rpt2, Rpt3

      * +---+-----+------+----------+
      * |id |Rpt1 |Rpt2  |Rpt3      |
      * +---+-----+------+----------+
      * |205|72   |36    | 12      |
**


df2=(df1.alias("d1")
.withColumn("new_calc",expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the error with a `Try` monad and return the original dataframe if `withColumn` fails.

```scala
import scala.util.Try

val df2 = Try(df1.withColumn("new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3")))
  .getOrElse(df1)
  .alias("d1")
```

You can also define it as a method if you want to reuse:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def withColumnIfExist(df: DataFrame, colName: String, col: Column) =
  Try(df.withColumn("new_calc",expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))).getOrElse(df)

val df3 = withColumnIfExist(df1, "new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))
  .alias("d1")
```

And if you need to chain multiple transformation you can use it with `transform`:

```scala
val df4 = df1.alias("d1")
  .transform(withColumnIfExist(_, "new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3")))
  .transform(withColumnIfExist(_, "new_calc_2", expr("Rpt1/Rpt2")))
```

Or you can implement it as an extension method with `implicit class`:

```scala
implicit class RichDataFrame(df: DataFrame) {
  def withColumnIfExist(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame =
    Try(df.withColumn("new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))).getOrElse(df)
}

val df5 = df1.alias("d1")
  .withColumnIfExist("new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))
  .withColumnIfExist("new_calc_2", expr("Rpt1/Rpt2"))
```

Since `withColumn` works with all datasets, and if you want `withColumnIfExist` to work generically for all datasets including dataframe:

```scala
implicit class RichDataset[A](ds: Dataset[A]) {
  def withColumnIfExist(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame =
    Try(ds.withColumn("new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))).getOrElse(ds.toDF)
}
```

Comment: Yes, in my example that would work.  I should have given more context to my dataframe, because df2 has many more transformations that occur.  I just simplified for the sake of this example.  I still want to return the rest of df2

Comment: Then you just chain it.`Try(df1.alias("d1").withColumn("new_calc", expr("Rpt2/Rpt3"))).getOrElse(df1).withColumn ...`